# Extracting last character of a sentence using Regex

Tags: c#, xml, regex, dom

I want to extract last character of a string. In fact I should make clear with example. Following is the string from which i want to extract:

```
<spara h-align="right" bgcolor="none" type="verse" id="1" pnum="1">
    <line>
        <emphasis type="italic">Approaches to Teaching and Learning</emphasis>
    </line>
</spara>
```

In the above string i want to insert space between the word "Learning" and "`</emphasis>`" if there is no space present.

Thanks,

Comment: Some users have suggested using Linq2XML or XPath, but you clearly ask about a regex. Can you elaborate whether that's a strict requirement here? Is the document so large that you cannot, or should not load it in a DOM?

Comment: Regardless of loading the full document, Regex as an XML parser is a doomed concept. If the document is too large to load in one go, .net offers XmlReader/XmlWriter which could be used to step through document nodes without fully loading the doc.

Comment: @spender: I couldn't agree more. And XmlReader/Writer are extremely fast in my experience.

Comment: @Muhammed Waqas: In an answer you posted a comment (please don't, see http://stackoverflow.com/faq) saying that you need the fast speed of a Regex to solve your issue. Regexes are only fast in certain tasks and slow in others. A one liner is in my answer, but you haven't commented there. As others have suggested, Regexes are not good for this particular task, nor are they fast (consider XmlReader if you need speed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like the following perhaps?

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, @"(>[^<]+[^ ])<", @"$1 <");
```

The solution assumes a sentence is between `>` and `<` and is one or more characters long.

Is the sentence really inside XML, or have you extracted it using any of the many XML or DOM methods? For instance, using this:

```
foreach(node in YourDOM.SelectNodes("//emphasis[@type='italic']"))
{
    string yourString = node.FirstChild.Value;
}
```

If so, if the string is on its own, you can do this instead, which is way simpler and safer:

```
Regex.Replace(yourString, "([^ ])$", "$1 ");
```

**EDIT:** I originally missed *if there's no space present*, the post above is edited with this information

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at some of the Linq to XML examples on here instead of using Regex.

Comment: no regex is not strictly required Linq 2 xml will also be highly appreciated if any one can help in this regard.

Answer (score 1):

With Linq to XML you can do it as follows:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("xmlfilename");

foreach (var emphasis in doc.Descendants("emphasis"))
{
      if (emphasis.Value.Last() != ' ')
         emphasis.Value += " ";
}
doc.Save("outputfilename");
```

Instead of files you may use streams, readers etc in the Load

Comment: +1 I like the clear example and the good advice (but it was not what was asked ;)